# Overall utility tool for a project that will create account lists for pulls

Tags: python, beginner, python-2.x

I'm creating a meta-utility tool for a project that I'm on that has a lot of repetitive tasks that can eat up a lot of time.  My goal with this tool is to eventually be able to automate, or at least facilitate, the vast-majority of grunt-work.  I eventually hope to add Django functionality to create reports from e-mails, as well as link it to a SQLite database.

This is an early version that only has two main functions.  It can either create a pull list (which control numbers to pull for proofing), or look up information in our audit records (and check to see if it printed in the TOT file).  I am using the `csv` module for `DictReader`.  One thing I'm curious about is how to not label the 'Empty Fields' in my `DictReader` if I know I won't use the information.

The reason you see me opening multiple files the way I do is due to the fact we only have version 2.6.6 on our server.

```
import csv


# Pull list program
def pull_list(level):
    acct_list_file = raw_input(r"Please enter the full file path for the list of account numbers (Please format your file so that each line only has one account number): ")
    run_num = str(raw_input("Please enter the run number (4 digits): "))
    repext = ''
    if level == 'p':
        repext = [redacted]
    else:
        repext = [redacted]
    print(repext)
    acct_list = []
    try:
        with open(acct_list_file, 'rbU') as infile:
            for line in infile:
                line = line.rstrip('\r\n')
                acct_list.append(line)  
    except IOError as e:
        print 'Unable to open the account number file: %s' % e.strerror

    try:
        with open(repext, 'rbU') as infile:
            print("Opening: ", repext)
            for line in infile:
                acct_num = line[33:41]
                ctrl_num = line[25:32]
                page_cnt = line[121:123]
                doc_type = line[2587:2600]
                if acct_num in acct_list:
                    print("%s found!" % acct_num)
                    print("Control Number: %s\n Total Page Count: %s\n BizBranding Type: %s" % (ctrl_num, page_cnt, doc_type))
    except IOError as e:
        print 'Unable to open the file: %s' % e.strerror


# Audit Info program                
def audit_info(level):
    print("\nThis program looks in the production audit.qty file using a property code.")
    prop_code = raw_input(r"Please enter the property code: ")
    prop_code_list = []
    piv_id = ''
    audit_in= ''
    tot_in = ''
    if level == 'p':
        audit_in = [redacted]
        tot_in = [redacted]
    else:
        audit_in = [redacted]
        tot_in = [redacted]
    try:
        audit_qty = open(audit_in, 'rbU') 
        tot_file = open(tot_in, 'rbU')

    except IOError as e:
        print 'Unable to open the file: %s' % e.strerror

    my_audit_reader = csv.DictReader(audit_qty, delimiter=';', restkey='Empty Field')
    my_audit_reader.fieldnames = ("Property Code",
                           "Pivot ID", 
                           "Inwork File", 
                           "Billing Manager E-mail", 
                           "Total Records", 
                           "Number of E-Bills", 
                           "Printed Records", 
                           "File Date", 
                           "Hour", 
                           "Minute", 
                           "Status")
    # Search for property code 
    for line in my_audit_reader:
        if prop_code == line['Property Code']:
            print '\nProperty Code: %s' % line['Property Code']
            print 'Pivot ID: %s' % line['Pivot ID']
            print 'Inwork File: %s' % line['Inwork File']
            print 'Billing Manager E-mail: %s' % line['Billing Manager E-mail']
            print 'Total Records: %s' % line['Total Records']
            print 'Number of E-Bills: %s' % line['Number of E-Bills']
            print 'Printed Records: %s' % line['Printed Records']
            print 'File Date: %s' % line['File Date']
            print 'Status: %s\n' % line['Status']
            prop_code_list.append(prop_code)
            piv_id = line['Pivot ID']

            # If found, then search the tot.qty file for it's corresponding status.
            my_tot_reader = csv.DictReader(tot_file, delimiter=';', restkey='Empty Field')
            my_tot_reader.fieldnames = ("Date", 
                                        "Pivot ID", 
                                        "Empty Field", 
                                        "Empty Field", 
                                        "Empty Field", 
                                        "Empty Field", 
                                        "Empty Field", 
                                        "Status")
            for row in my_tot_reader:
                if row['Pivot ID'] == piv_id:
                    print('\nStatus in the TOT file is: {0}\n'.format(row['Status']))


    if prop_code not in prop_code_list:
        print '\nProperty code not found.\n'

    audit_qty.close()
    tot_file.close()


# Main loop             
def main():
    print("Welcome to the Utility Tool!\n")

    while True:
        usr_input = raw_input("""Please select one of the following options:

            1. Pull List 
            2. Audit Info 
            3. Approval Files (WIP)
            4. Reporting Services (WIP)
            5. SQLLite Database (WIP)
            Quit = 'q'  
            Selection: """)
        if usr_input == 'q': break
        level = raw_input("Please enter your environment level (p for prod, t for test): ")

        if level != "p" and level != "t":
            print("\nLevel selection not recognized, please try again.\n")
            continue
        else:
            print('\nLevel is: {0}\n'.format(level))
        # Pull List Program
        if usr_input == '1':
            pull_list(level)

        #Audit Info Program     
        elif usr_input == '2':
            audit_info(level)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Performance

For each line in the audit file that has a matching property code,
you re-read the "tot file" to find a matching Pivot ID.
This is inefficient.
It would be better to read the "tot file" only once,
before processing the audit file,
and build a dictionary of Pivot ID -> Status mappings.

#### Working with files

In some places you used the `with open(...) as` syntax,
but in some other places you didn't.
Use it everywhere, so that you don't need to call `.close()` manually.

#### Empty fields

> One thing I'm curious about is how to not label the 'Empty Fields' in my DictReader if I know I won't use the information.

The thing is, the `.fieldnames` attribute needs to be a list-like structure,
with elements corresponding to each column in the file.
And, for example, if you want to use only column 6,
you need to set some values in the list positions before that column too.

One thing you can do is instead of writing "Empty Field",
you could write empty strings "", which is shorter.
Another way is to set the attribute to a sufficiently large list of empty strings in a first step, and in a second step overwrite the elements that you're interested in, like this:

```
my_tot_reader.fieldnames = [''] * 99
my_tot_reader.fieldnames[1] = "Pivot ID"
my_tot_reader.fieldnames[7] = "Status"
```

Comment: I thought about that, but as there is at most one property code to look for, I wasn't sure if it was worth it.  Noted though!  As far as the with open() syntax, since I'm using version 2.6.6 it won't let me open multiple files on the same line, should I open the TOT file when I'm ready to use it?

Answer (score 1):

**Style**

- I suggest sticking with ' or " .  Sometimes you may have to mix them but you mixed them for strings.   I prefer ' but you can prefer "
- You mixed print functions and built-ins.  Python2.x uses the built-in print, while python3 likes it as a function.  I suggest doing it as a function to make it portable in the future, I showed a few examples below with the ## lines being your old code.  .format is your bridging friend (and .format in 2.6 requires the {0} where 2.7 you can use positional {})
- like mentioned, pep8 is highly regarded in the python community, and you should become familiar with it.  The biggest items being spaces after , and 80char limit on lines.  Note I did this for you below so you can use it as an example
- added docstrings to your methods/functions.

an example:

```
'''
my program
'''
import csv


# Pull list program
def pull_list(level):
    '''
     pull function docs here
    '''
    acct_list_file = raw_input(r'Please enter the full file path for the list'
                               ' of account numbers (Please format your file'
                               ' so that each line only has one account number): ')
    run_num = str(raw_input("Please enter the run number (4 digits): "))
    repext = ''
    if level == 'p':
        repext = None ## propriatary action here
    else:
        repext = None ## propriatary action here
    print(run_num, repext)  ## debugline?
    acct_list = []
    try:
        with open(acct_list_file, 'rbU') as infile:
            for line in infile:
                line = line.rstrip('\r\n')
                acct_list.append(line)
    except IOError as e:
        ##print 'Unable to open the account number file: %s' % e.strerror
        print('Unable to open the account number file: {0})'.format(e.strerror))

    try:
        with open(repext, 'rbU') as infile:
            print('Opening: {0}'.format(repext))
            ##print("Opening: ", repext)
            for line in infile:
                acct_num = line[33:41]
                ctrl_num = line[25:32]
                page_cnt = line[121:123]
                doc_type = line[2587:2600]
                if acct_num in acct_list:
                    print("{0} found!".format(acct_num))
                    ##print("%s found!" % acct_num)
                    print('Control Number: {0}\n '
                          'Total Page Count: {1}\n'
                          'BizBranding Type: {2}'.format(ctrl_num,
                                                        page_cnt,
                                                        doc_type))
                    ##print("Control Number: %s\n Total Page Count: %s\n BizBranding Type: %s" % (ctrl_num, page_cnt, doc_type))
    except IOError as e:
        print('Unable to open the file: {0}'.format(e.strerror))


# Audit Info program 
def audit_info(level):
    print('\nThis program looks in the production audit.qty file using a property code.')
    prop_code = raw_input(r'Please enter the property code: ')
    prop_code_list = []
    piv_id = ''
    audit_in = ''
    tot_in = ''
    if level == 'p':
        audit_in = None ## propriatary action here
        tot_in = None ## propriatary action here
    else:
        audit_in = None ## propriatary action here
        tot_in = None ## propriatary action here
    try:
        audit_qty = open(audit_in, 'rbU')
        tot_file = open(tot_in, 'rbU')

    except IOError as e:
        print('Unable to open the file: {0}'.format(e.strerror))

    my_audit_reader = csv.DictReader(audit_qty,
                                     delimiter=';',
                                     restkey='Empty Field')
    my_audit_reader.fieldnames = ("Property Code",
                                  "Pivot ID",
                                  "Inwork File",
                                  "Billing Manager E-mail",
                                  "Total Records",
                                  "Number of E-Bills",
                                  "Printed Records",
                                  "File Date",
                                  "Hour",
                                  "Minute",
                                  "Status")
    # Search for property code
    for line in my_audit_reader:
        if prop_code == line['Property Code']:
            print('\nProperty Code: {0}'.format(line['Property Code']))
            print('Pivot ID: {0}'.format(line['Pivot ID']))
            print('Inwork File: {0}'.format(line['Inwork File']))
            print('Billing Manager E-mail: {0}'
                  .format(line['Billing Manager E-mail']))
            print('Total Records: {0}'.format(line['Total Records']))
            print('Number of E-Bills: {0}'.format(line['Number of E-Bills']))
            print('Printed Records: {0}'.format(line['Printed Records']))
            print('File Date: {0}'.format(line['File Date']))
            print('Status: {0}\n'.format(line['Status']))
            prop_code_list.append(prop_code)
            piv_id = line['Pivot ID']

            # If found, then search the tot.qty file for it's corresponding status.
            my_tot_reader = csv.DictReader(tot_file, delimiter=';', restkey='Empty Field')
            my_tot_reader.fieldnames = ("Date",
                                        "Pivot ID",
                                        "Empty Field",
                                        "Empty Field",
                                        "Empty Field",
                                        "Empty Field",
                                        "Empty Field",
                                        "Status")
            for row in my_tot_reader:
                if row['Pivot ID'] == piv_id:
                    print('\nStatus in the TOT file is: {0}\n'.format(row['Status']))


    if prop_code not in prop_code_list:
        print('\nProperty code not found.\n')

    audit_qty.close()
    tot_file.close()


# Main loop
def main():
    '''
    let's do this
    '''
    print('Welcome to the Utility Tool!\n')
    usr_input = None
    while True:
        usr_input = raw_input("""Please select one of the following options:

            1. Pull List 
            2. Audit Info 
            3. Approval Files (WIP)
            4. Reporting Services (WIP)
            5. SQLLite Database (WIP)
            Quit = 'q'  
            Selection: """).lower()
        if usr_input == 'q':
            break
        level = raw_input('Please enter your environment level'
                          '(p for prod, t for test): ').lower()

        if level != 'p' and level != 't':
            print('\nLevel selection not recognized, please try again.\n')
            continue
        else:
            print('\nLevel is: {0}\n'.format(level))
        # Pull List Program
        if usr_input == '1':
            pull_list(level)

        #Audit Info Program     
        elif usr_input == '2':
            audit_info(level)

        continue

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```